# Disable button while input is not valid Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I'd like to make certain input-fields only available for `integer` or `decimal`-values. So I got the following code:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" [(ngModel)]="myValue" pInputText class="medium-field"
    (change)="calculate()"/>
```

So this field is marked if the pattern does not match the input. Still I would like to disable the `submit`-button while the pattern is not matched. Can I somehow access that value as a boolean or is there another way?

Comment: Easiest way is probably to use Reactive Forms in Angular; but explaining what those are is probably beyond the scope of answering a question.  An alternate way would be to trigger a `buttonDisabled` flag in your calculate function that controls whether your button is disabled or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't want to use Reactive Forms, you can do:

```
<input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" [(ngModel)]="myValue" #myInput />
<button [disabled]="!myInput.validity.valid">Submit</button>
```

That will disable your submit button if the HTML validity of your input is invalid.

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/6zm41m63xz) is a working example.

I would also suggest you use `type="number"` in your `input`.

Answer (score 1):

The form will be marked automatically as invalid if your input didn't matched with your pattern.

You can just use:

```
<form novalidate
      #form="ngForm">

     /* Your inputs */

     <button type="button"
             [disabled]="form.invalid">     // form as per the referenced #form="ngForm"
                                            // Disables if your inputs are invalid or doesn't meet with its pattern
         Submit
     </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

try form validation for it.using *ngIf and

```
<button type="submit" [disabled]="form.invalid">SEND</button>
```